# If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with zero integral over every rectangle of area $1,$ then $f = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

> If $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with zero
> integral over every rectangle of area $1,$ prove $f = 0.$

Using induction and a shifting argument for the base case, I managed to show that if $ABCD$ is a rectangle with integer area, then $$f(A) + f(C) = f(B) + f(D) \, \, (*)$$ I think this almost solves the problem, I just need to draw the right diagram now. Unfortunately, I'm having difficulties coming up with a diagram that works.

I drew a $2 \times 2$ square with vertices $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I,$ applied $(*)$ on all sorts of squares within this square, summed the results, and then tried to cancel as many terms on both sides as possible. However, no matter which sums I took, I would always end up with either $0 = 0$ or a trivial result of the form $(*).$ How do I find the right diagram? I tried drawing $3 \times 3, \sqrt{2} \times \sqrt{2}$ and even $\sqrt{3} \times \sqrt{3}$ squares, but ran into the same problem (at one point, I thought I had proven that $f(x,y) = f(x+\sqrt{3},y) = f(x+\sqrt{2},y),$ which would show $f$ is constant after employing the density of $\{a\sqrt{2}+b\sqrt{3} : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ in $\mathbb{R},$ but it turned out I made a mistake when adding terms in both cases). Any ideas?

Comment: This appeared as problem [A6 on the 2012 Putnam, and the solution](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2012s.pdf) is correspondingly difficult. It does certainly resonate with the ideas you've described though!

Comment: Kindly take one of those answers and post it below as answer. Or give me the permission to do so (with explanation).